# GTX 1050 and GTX 1050 Ti-based cards power socket?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Some graphics card have a power socket in addition to drawing power from the PCIe bus. Is this the case for nVIDIA GTX 1050 and GTX 1050 Ti-based cards? That is, do

- No vendors' 1050 and 1050 Ti cards have an extra socket?
- All vendors' 1050 and 1050 Ti cards have an extra socket?
- Some cards by some vendors have one, and others don't?

I'm looking at images of these cards and they don't show the top or the back side where a socket might be placed.

Note: I am *not* asking for a recommendation for a card! I just need to know whether there's a chance I might need to get a different PSU to support such a card (I have a rather old one).

Comment: The GTX 1050/1050Ti is a chipset manufactured by nVidia, but the cards are made by lots of different companies and use different architectures for cooling and other card options. You'll need to add more information to make this question even answerable, but you should also keep in mind that this is currently a hardware shopping recommendation question, and is off-topic for SuperUser.

Comment: Further, the answer to your question will be found in the technical documentation for the brand/model card you choose.

Comment: @music2myear: See edit.

Comment: Once again, this is answered by reasonable effort on your part. Visit NewEgg.com, filter the video card results by GPU type, then look at the specs.

Comment: Also, some cards have the power connector on the top edge rather than the end. NewEgg tends to have more/better image options as well for this search.

Comment: @music2myear: That would have at most partially answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will entirely depend on the model. Some are listed as requiring a 6-pin power connector (like the [EVGA GeForce GTX 1050 FTW GAMING, 02G-P4-6157-KR](https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-6157-KR)), while others don't mention it in their specs at all ([ASUS EX-GTX1050-2G](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/EX-GTX1050-2G/specifications/)).

I would investigate the model you plan on buying first through the manufacturers website and if in doubt either contact their support center, or the support center of the retailer you plan on purchasing your hardware from.

Comment: Thank you, although, frankly - looking at the images of that FTW card I can't see where the connector is located. Also - just to make sure - there's just one type of a 6-pin power connector, right? They don't have multiple versions with different shapes of the plastic surrounding the pins ?

Comment: Yea, they don't normally show the power connector in official photos. Most of the time it it located at the end of the card, opposite to the output connectors. Unless you have some extremely non-standard PSU, the 6 (or potentially 4+2) pin connector will be the same as any other PSU.